# Python DataFrame for Stock data - Drop Function Not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import sys
#df = DataFrame(table, columns=headers)
#df = DataFrame(table)


#Code to take data from Quandl
df=quandl.get("NSE/BHEL",start_date="2017-06-15", end_date="2017-06-29")
df.rename(columns = {'Last':'Adj Close'}, inplace = True)
df=df[['Open','High','Low','Adj Close','Close']]
df.drop(df.index[2,10])
```

I have the above code to fetch data from quandl, it gives Date,Open High,Low,Adj Close,Close data

After getting this data i want to delete row 1(not index ,Data row) to Row 10 but using the drop function given above nothing works it gives same data as we receive it from quandl. I hope experts can help me with clean code to achieve this.Please give me the code for python3.6

```
              Open    High     Low  Adj Close   Close
Date
2017-06-15  138.25  140.55  137.40     138.70  139.10
2017-06-16  139.35  140.70  137.90     138.10  138.30
2017-06-19  138.60  139.40  137.85     138.00  138.10
2017-06-20  138.50  138.80  137.40     137.60  137.80
2017-06-21  137.10  138.75  135.75     136.65  136.65
2017-06-22  136.75  138.65  136.45     136.75  137.15
2017-06-23  136.60  137.50  132.15     134.95  135.00
2017-06-27  135.05  135.55  130.80     134.55  134.40
2017-06-28  134.10  136.80  132.50     136.55  136.30
```

This is the data i am getting before and after drop function; i want Date 15-06-2017 to 23-06-2017 complete row data to be removed and df stores only 27,28th row data ,what is the efficient way of getting it done in python3.6

Comment: Delete row 1, not index? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Why dont you use iloc to select rows from specific index?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need select data by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if need select by position or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if need select dates outside of range:

```
df = df.iloc[7:]
print (df)
              Open    High    Low  Adj Close  Close
Date                                               
2017-06-27  135.05  135.55  130.8     134.55  134.4
2017-06-28  134.10  136.80  132.5     136.55  136.3

df = df[(df.index > '2017-06-23') | (df.index < '2017-06-15')]
print (df)
              Open    High    Low  Adj Close  Close
Date                                               
2017-06-27  135.05  135.55  130.8     134.55  134.4
2017-06-28  134.10  136.80  132.5     136.55  136.3
```

Solution with [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) or [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.difference(pd.date_range('2017-06-15','2017-06-23'))]
print (df)
              Open    High    Low  Adj Close  Close
2017-06-27  135.05  135.55  130.8     134.55  134.4
2017-06-28  134.10  136.80  132.5     136.55  136.3
```

---

```
df = df[~df.index.isin(pd.date_range('2017-06-15','2017-06-23'))]
print (df)
              Open    High    Low  Adj Close  Close
Date                                               
2017-06-27  135.05  135.55  130.8     134.55  134.4
2017-06-28  134.10  136.80  132.5     136.55  136.3
```

But if need really `drop`:

```
df = df.drop(df.loc['2017-06-15':'2017-06-23'].index)
print (df)
              Open    High    Low  Adj Close  Close
Date                                               
2017-06-27  135.05  135.55  130.8     134.55  134.4
2017-06-28  134.10  136.80  132.5     136.55  136.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [between](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.between.html)

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime("15-06-2017")
end_date = pd.to_datetime("23-06-2017") 
df[~df.reset_index().Date.between(start,end)]
```

ouput

```
        Date    Open    High    Low  Adj_Close  Close
7 2017-06-27  135.05  135.55  130.8     134.55  134.4
8 2017-06-28  134.10  136.80  132.5     136.55  136.3
```